# Compile Kotlin to JavaScript

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I've started looking into Kotlin and I'd like to use it instead of TypeScript for my front end language. Both compile down to JavaScript so I'd like to set it up so that I make a Kotlin file, lets call it `myFile.kt`, then when I run the compiler it makes a `myFile.js` file.

Just like how TypeScript takes a `myFile.ts` and compiles it to a `myFile.js`.

I'm using the latest version of IntelliJ 15 with release candidate 1 of Kotlin.

I've been searching all over the internet for the way to do this but so far all I've found is setting up IntelliJ so that Kotlin creates a JavaScript library from your code in a JAR file. I also haven't been able to get that to compile any of the `kt` files in my project (they were previously `js` files).

Is what I'd like to do currently possible or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should help:

https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/test/resources/testProject/kotlin2JsProject/libraryProject/build.gradle

There are sample of library project. JS sources can be founded in `buildDir`.
So yes, you can get js files from Kotlin sources.

Kotlin language a very different from JavaScript (even ES6), so you can't just rename `js` to `kt`, this will not work. You need rewrite javascript source files to Kotlin.

For example:

```
console.log('Hello, World!');
```

Should be rewritten as:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  println("Hello, World!")
}
```